# How to shift Labels on x Axis python and Center Bars, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I shift labels to one position left? It looks like labels are starting from `1`, not from zero. And how can I center the bars and get some space from left `y` axis and right `y` axis?

Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))

index = np.arange(5) # np.arange(numCp)
bar_width = 0.70

opacity = 0.4
error_config = {'ecolor': '0.6'}

rects1 = plt.bar(index, [400, 555, 666, 777, 888], bar_width,
             alpha=opacity,
             color='b',
             error_kw=error_config,
             align='center')

plt.ylabel('Seconds')
plt.title('Seconds to Process')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ['Igorj', 'Borja', 'Vasja', 'Sanja', 'Petja'],     rotation=45)
ax.yaxis.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is my resulting figure:

[image: My Result]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must change this:

```
plt.xticks(index, ['Igorj', 'Borja', 'Vasja', 'Sanja', 'Petja'], rotation=45)
```